# Vue transition-group not working

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, transition

I want to use transition-group in Vue, it works fine without nesting，but when I use it like this, it acts strangely.

Then I check out animations in developer tools, find that all the list items' transition-duration is actually zero.

[developer tools' snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq2ey.png)

Then I tried to add `display: block !important` in style, but it still didn't work

> transitionDelay in style doesn't affect the result, I already had a try.
>
> and it may suddenly work fine with the same code

For better understanding, [here is what it looks like](http://report.hustonline.net/mobile/index.html) (need to open with phone or develop tools' mobile devices, if it redirect to the website for desktop, change to mobile mode and then refresh)

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
.slide-enter-active,
.slide-leave-active {
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.slide-enter,
.slide-leave-active {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all .6s;
}
.list-enter,
.list-leave-active {
  transform: translateX(-350px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<transition name="fade">
  <div class="black-layout" v-show="isShowCatalog">
    <transition name="slide">
      <div v-show="isShowCatalog">
        <transition-group tag="ul" name="list">
          <li v-for="(value, index) of catalog" :key="index + 1" v-show="isShowCatalog" :style="{ transitionDelay: 0.02 * index + 's' }" @click="clickCatalog" :data-search="value.searchStr">{{ value.name }}</li>
        </transition-group>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 10):

When using `transition-group` in vue.js the key of the items should be a unique property. Using the `index` from the `v-for` would work in this case because when the **position** of the item changes, the index of the `v-for` does not change with them. For your case, you could use a property of each item you are looping through if it is an object or the item itself if they are an array and unique values.

```
// If catalog is an object
<transition-group tag="ul" name="list">
  <li v-for="value of catalog" :key="value.<propertyName>" v-show="isShowCatalog" :style="{ transitionDelay: 0.02 * index + 's' }" @click="clickCatalog" :data-search="value.searchStr">{{ value.name }}</li>
</transition-group>



// If catalog is an array and unique
<transition-group tag="ul" name="list">
  <li v-for="value of catalog" :key="value" v-show="isShowCatalog" :style="{ transitionDelay: 0.02 * index + 's' }" @click="clickCatalog" :data-search="value.searchStr">{{ value.name }}</li>
</transition-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Change code: delete index in v-for

```
<li v-for="value of catalog" :key="value.index">
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show your answer as code. To do that indent it using 4 spaces. :) I'll go ahead and edit your answer a bit to demonstrate.